# maven checkstyle sql/plsql plugin

Tags: sql, oracle, maven, checkstyle

Does anybody know how to check sql files for custom checkstyle rules. For example:

ALTER TABLE MYLOCALSCHEME.MYTABLE...

should be

ALTER TABLE MYTABLE...

without schema name,

because there are different schemes in different environment.

Comment: pmd is not support plsql: "The programming language to be analyzed by CPD. Valid values are currently java, javascript or jsp."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check sql files for custom checkstyle rules

Unless you want to make your own antlr parser for the language, you can use `RegexpSingleline` to create some basic rules using regular expression.

Example Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="sql"/>

  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="ALTER TABLE \w+\.\w+"/>
    <property name="minimum" value="0"/>
    <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

A custom parser would involve a new g4 Lexer and Parser, a new class that iterates through the nodes (like TreeWalker), an AST class (like DetailAST), a base class for all new checks (AbstractCheck), and then any and all new Checks you want.